# facebook-unity-sdk WP8 and Windows Store

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

On behalf of the Unity developers of Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store apps, I would like to ask you guys to support those platforms to the sdk. It would be fantastic.

Best regards

Comment: We are collecting feedback on what should be done next for the SDK and we are taking in feedback like this from our developers to help us decide.  Thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: I agree with this post. It would definately be great to see Win8/WP8 support in the Facebook SDK.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't a question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for an SDK, and not a programming question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a Facebook support request, not a programming question.

Comment: The thing is there seems to be no way to get to facebook with this request, as its really needed